# Función asociada al estado de un @Html.Checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, mvc, razor

debo programar la funcionalidad de aceptar o no los términos y condicioes de la aplicación. Lo estamos haciendo en Visual Studio, bajo la estructura mvc de asp.net.

La idea es que cuando el CheckBox esté `checked`, habilite el `@Html.Button`.

Este es el código del botón:

```
@Html.CtrlButton(viewName: "vMonedero", id: "btnCreate", label: "Crear", onClickFunction: "Create", buttonType: "success")
```

Este es el código del checkbox:

```
@Html.CheckBox("terminos", false)
```

Este es el código del script que hice:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function disableSending() {
        document.getElementById('#btnCreate').disabled;
        if (document.getElementsByName('terminos').checked = true) {
            document.getElementById('#btnCreate').disabled = false
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema exactamente?

Comment: Que no me deshabilita el botón, aun así puede hacer el registro. No sé si el problema está en el script

Comment: Por una parte, en ningún lugar indicas que se llame a 'disableSeding()'. Sin embargo, dentro del código de dicha función hay varios elementos incorrectos: la primera linea, "document.getElementById('#btnCreate').disabled;" no hace nada, ya que esto retorna un valor; el condicional, debe ser con '==' no con '='.

Comment: ¿Puedo llamar la función desde el @Htm.CheckBox?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        document.getElementById('#btnCreate').disabled == true;
        if (document.getElementsByName('terminos').checked == true) {
            document.getElementById('#btnCreate').disabled == false
        }
    });
</script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

espero que te sirva, lo probe.

PD: por la parte del btn solo necesitas el id de este.

```
<button class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" value="aceptar" id="btnCreate">TEST</button>
@Html.CheckBox("terminos", false, new { @class = "isCheck" })

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#btnCreate').prop('disabled', true);

    $('.isCheck').change(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            $('#btnCreate').prop('disabled', false);
        }
        else {
            $('#btnCreate').prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias bro!